# Unable to run wpf project which refers a CLR project

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, clr, release

I have created a CLR project library (ClassLibrary1) with configuration Release(x64). And also added a new wpf project (TestwpfOpenCV) on the solution of  ClassLibrary1. I added the CLR as a reference in my WPF project. I tried to build both projects in X64 Release.
But I got an exception on button click of wpf project.

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in PresentationCore.dll
>   Could not load file or assembly 'ClassLibrary1.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Is `ClassLibrary1.dll` in the bin folder with `exe` ? Are project dependencies set correctly?

Comment: As @Sinatr asked, do you have the `ClassLibrary1.dll` in the target directory for the `TestWpfopenCV` application?

Comment: It's difficult to say without seeing the dependencies of ClassLibrary1. But since it seems to be an OpenCV wrapper I assume it relies on other libraries, these aren't always accessible to projects that use ClassLibrary1 so it might be worth checking if TestWpfopenCV has the dependencies of ClassLibrary1.dll with it's binaries

Comment: ClassLibrary1.dll might be there, but its native dependencies (opencv native libraries) might not.

Comment: Please check my updated question . ClassLibrary1.dll is there in the bin folder.

Comment: @LexLi after seeing your comment I have copied cuda.Inl.hpp and mat.Inl.hpp to bin folder and tried. Still shows same issue. Please suggest.

Comment: @user2431727 The ClassLibrary1.dll dependencies will be either *.dll or *.lib files (in this case). Ensure that your TestWpfopencv project has these in its target directory as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it solved by downloading latest version of opencv. Also removed the environment variable which is created for opencv path. And copied all the dlls from that path to project's bin folder.